# I can't log into the administrator account in Windows 10, the account is not activated

Tags: windows

Я в Windows 10 в учетной записи пользователя. Аккаунт администратора не активен. Я не могу войти в Windows PowerShell (Admin) для активации. Я не могу удалить файлы или программы. Откроется окно «Вы хотите, чтобы это приложение могло вносить изменения в ваше устройство», и есть только кнопка «Нет». Помоги мне, пожалуйста

Comment: Если нет полных прав - значит их надо получить. 1. Повысить права текущей учётки. 2. Активировать Администратора. 3. Создать новую с полными правами. Лучше всего делать через `ERD Commander`.

Comment: А как я могу это сделать? Может у вас есть видео, чтобы увидеть как это делается.

Comment: Конкретно у меня нет, но есть куча руководств в интернете. С картинками и описанием. Тут вопрос в другом: ПОЧЕМУ у тебя нет прав? Хочешь поставить пару прог на работе в обход сисадмина? Добром это не кончится: можно отгрести от начальства и потерять хорошее расположение самого админа. И ещё неизвестно что хуже. Если у тебя система дома потеряла права, потому что ты качнула вирус, то лучше всё переставить с форматированием разделов.

Comment: Я просто отформатировала свой компьютер, создала пользователя, администратор не был активирован. Я хотела, чтобы был только один пользователь (то есть, работала в учетной записи администратора), активировала администратора и удалила пользователя, загрузила программы, но когда я включила компьютер во второй раз, все программы были удалены. Я создала новую учетную запись, как и раньше, и деактивировала администратора. И теперь я не могу даже удалить файлы.

Comment: "Чем такого лечить - проще новго родить". Ставь всё заново и открой для себя волшебные слова `backup`, `clonezilla`, `devops`. Раз чешутся руки тюнить систему с удалениями папок `boot`, `system32` и сносом ненужных файлов типа `ntuser.dat`.

Comment: И ещё, откуда такая любовь ко встроенной учётке "Администратор"? Чё вы все на неё так молитесь? У кого не посмотрю - половина под ней сидит.